# TypeScript - How to convert array of functions into array of the function results

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm pretty much trying to convert this type

```
type FnArray = [() => number, () => string, () => boolean]
```

into this type

```
type ValueArray = [number, string, boolean];
```

Keep in mind that this is only example and I need it for my generic array of functions. So I'm also looking for some generic solution.

I'm pretty sure it needs to invole `ReturnType` utility type and some kind of type iteration (possibly with just spread operator, but I'm not really sure about that).

Will apprectiate any help or link to a solution I wasn't able to find one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 3.1+:
You can use mapped types on tuples and arrays.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html

So, you can do

```
type FnArray = [() => number, () => string, () => boolean]

type ReturnTypeArray<T extends ((...args: any[]) => any)[]> = { [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]> };

type ValueArray = ReturnTypeArray<FnArray>
```

Comment: It makes sense. Didn't think of interpreting the array as an object. Thanks a lot. :)